# Do I need to answer "yes" to the Encryption used question in the app store submission process as I am using Three20 library?

Tags: iphone, app-store, three20

i am going to submit my application to Appstore. i have one question as i am using Three20 library in my project to load thumbnail images from server.

My question do I need to answer "yes" to the Encryption used question in the app store submission process?

while review the library i found Three20 library using md5 encryption so please advice me in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Md5 isn't encryption, it's simply a hashing algorithm.

When you submit your app, you are asked this question (as you already know). If you answer yes to the question, you're asked this next question:

> Is encryption used for anything other than authentication?

If you answer no, that's it, thats the end of encryption questions.

If you answer yes, then you'll be required to provide details of what you are encrypting and why. Then you'll be required to fill out the necessary legal documentation that surrounds encryption export laws for certain countries.

So if you're only using md5 for hashing, or even if you're not using it directly (it's only in use by Three20) you don't need to answer yes to these questions.